# Java: if, switch or question mark double point

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

Which of the following methods is the fastest?

```
int i;
String s;
```

1. If Else

```
if(i == 0)
    s = "Case A"
else if(i == 1)
    s = "Case B"
else
    s = "Case C"
```

2. Switch

```
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        s = "Case A"; break;
    case 1:
        s = "Case B"; break;
    default:
        s = "Case C"; break;
}
```

3. ? and :

```
s = (i == 0 ? "Case A" : (i == 1 ? "Case B" : "Case C"))
```

Also, are method 1 and 3 compiled with the same output?

Comment: My recommendation: Enter these instructions in your IDE, add a loop to repeat 100,000 times. Borrow a watch, run and time. You'll have the best possible answer to the question.

Comment: @mins or they can use Date.getTime() before & after and do math :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at *your code* , With any modern compiler all of the above conditionals compile into the same instructions. Focus on readability and maintainability of your code. They have negligible effect on performance

You can use ternary in places where you can't use if-else or switch for example

`System.out.println ("Good morning " + (p.female) ? "Miss " : "Mister " + p.getName ());`

Focus on readability and maintainability. Can't stress this enough when you start dealing with a large code base.

But lets say you had more conditionals then switch would be preferred because it would be more concise, readable, and slightly more performing

Check out this link here- http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many if/else statement you have.  The general rule of thumb is that if you have more than three if/else statements a switch is faster.  This is just for average cases though and stops being true though if the first if is true 95% of the time.

Your first and third case should take the same amount of time if I'm not mistaken.  I think they compile to the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` is faster than `if-else`.. and performance of `if-else` is approximately equal to that of `ternary`. So, logically `switch` is faster than all.

[Visit](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SpeedTestIfElseSwitch.aspx) to find the raw comparision and similar test carried out by a fellow like you!

Better worry about readabililty and maintainability of the code in question. If there are more than two if/else blocks backed together or if its size is unpredictable, then you may wish to opt for a `switch` statement.

Comment: if I have only two possible outcomes like situation then what would be the better option, if-else or ternary?

Comment: Depends. If am dealing with direct value comparisons and assignments, i'll go with ternary.Short,plot more concise. However if i dont wish to sacrifice readability over conciseness, i'd go with if-else block. Good example: int result = check() ? 1 : 0; Bad example: int result = firstCheck() ? 1 : secondCheck() ? 1 : thirdCheck() ? 1 : 0; –  Lalit Rao 1 hour ago